# Debug wrong copy of project in Asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

i just upgrade my MVC 1 project to MVC 3. and now in my current project [MVC3] have no views as old have.

when i run them or debug i found that everything i can see means all pages i can see by debug this blanks views project who still not have any views.

i am wonder. i restart them and try by disk cleaning but their is nothing goes right.

don't wonder if you not understand it:-

i have two project [first in MVC1 and 2nd in MVC3]

MVC1 project have views.

MVC3 project still not have any views but for testing i make blanks page.

i wonder by debugging blanks views MVC3 project i can see everything who already My MVC1 project have.

why this problem come are reason is that same name of both project.

i am trying this when i run only project MVC3 [no-views] but they show me everything i can see in MVC1 project.

well are their any way to solve this problem

NExT STEP:

i found that the problem is that i have two copy of a project.

first in MVC 1 and 2nd in MVC 3 [razor]

i found that when  i run in MVC3 project who is in D drive the code they debug is MVC1 who is in C drive.

i find out this by checking server.mappath  i wonder how they debug mvc1 project when i debug MVC3 project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run clean solution, ensure there is no pdb file from previous project is there in bin folder

Comment: this is a bug atleat no sollution i hear from MS when i reported them.